# Web Role in Azure Cloud service access permission and persistent storage?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

Just deployed a boilerplate Web Role in Azure Cloud service. Upon launching, it seems the default current dir is "d:\windows\system32\inetsrv" and home is "F:\sitesroot\0"

It seems I have limited write permissions, no delete permissions.

2 questions:

1. How much storage is there on this server under F:\sitesroot? Is it persistent?
2. How do I control the default permission/access of a web role?

Answer (score 1):

You should be reading/writing to a LocalStorage resource.  When you define a LocalStorage resource a folder is configured on the C: drive with appropriate size and permissions setup.

There is no persistent local storage for WebRoles.  If you need something persistent then you should use Azure storage (blobs/tables) or something else like SQL Azure.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee758708.aspx for more information, and http://convective.wordpress.com/2009/05/09/local-storage-on-windows-azure/ for sample code.

Comment: Thank you so much. So when you say there's no persistent storage, do you mean the drive is automatically cleaned after a while?

Comment: When updates are applied or cloud services are redeployed, the entire VM can be recreated.

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2012/10/05/windows-azure-disk-partition-preservation.aspx for a list of the scenarios and what happens to each drive letter in these scenarios.